Закрепившееся написание "веретеница" с одной Н
Почему слово "веретеница" закреплено в словарях с "н", если этимологически оно идет от "веретена". Стало быть, должна была быть такая модель: слово с основой на "н" (веретено") + ниц = веретЕнница, как в случае с "поленницей".


Происхождение слов

Ломкая веретеница  — вид безногих ящериц из семейства веретеницевых. Название «веретеница» происходит от веретена, которое формой напоминает эту ящерицу, а «ломкая» — от свойства отбрасывать хвост.
Общеславянское слово веретено образовано от основы vert (от этой же основы образован и глагол вертеть). Буквальное значение слова веретено — «вертящаяся палочка».
Происхождение слова полено точно не установлено; ученые предполагают, что оно связано с древнерусским глаголом полети 'гореть' того же корня, что пылать, палить, пламя.

Словообразование

Исторически слова веретено и полено образованы от глагольной основы, причем в обоих случаях использовался словообразовательный формант ЕН.
Примечание.  Форманты ЕН/Н можно считать интерфиксом, то есть элементом, который в данном случае вставляется между корневой морфемой и окончанием.
Полен/о — полен/ниц/а. Удвоение НН на стыке корня и приставки.
Можно предположить, что слово веретеница образовано непосредственно от глагола вертеть с помощью суффикса ЕНИЦ: верт/е/ть — верет/ениц/а. Сравнить: учить — уч/еник — уче/ниц/а.

Другие примеры по теме:

Приданое — бес/придан/ниц/а, но мороженый — морожен/иц/а.
Птица – птенец, первый – первенец, свояк – свояченица – суффиксы ЕНЕЦ (мужской род) и ЕНИЦ (женский род) – единичные суффиксы с одной буквой Н.

А почему именно от глагола "вертеть"?

И веретено, и веретеница в конечном счете соотносятся с глаголом вертеть. Веретеница похожа на веретено, но словообразование здесь независимое. В качестве мотивирующего слова выступает глагол, и эта модель используется в языке, что видно по другим примерам.
